# How to use jquery for tables in ruby on rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, html-table

I am  new in developing web apps in RoR and I need some help with jQuery.

I have a webpage with a table of messages and two buttons for moderating - Accept and Decline message.

**.../view/messages/index.html.erb**

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>Moderate</h1>
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Client</th>
        <th>№</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Content</th>
        <th>Tariff</th>
        <th>FromDate</th>
        <th>TillDate</th>
        <th>Cost</th>
        <th>Status</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <%= render @messages %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
 <%= will_paginate @messages %>
</div>
```

**.../view/messages/_message.html.erb**

```
<tr>
  <% if current_user.admin? %>
    <th><%= message.user.name %></th>
  <% end %>
  <th><%= message.id %></th>
  <th><%= message.created_at %></th>
  <th><%= image_tag message.content_url(:thumb) if message.content? %></th>
  <th><%= message.tariff %></th>
  <th><%= message.fromdate %></th>
  <th><%= message.tilldate %></th>
  <th><%= message.cost %></th>
  <th><%= message.status %>
    <% if current_user.admin? && message.status=="Moderating" %>
      <div class="btn-group" id="btn-group-<%= message.id %>">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Accept</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Decline</button>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </th>
</tr>
```

When the button "Accept" is clicked I need to change the corresponding Message status to "Accepted" in the database (sqlite3), the corresponding row of table should be bootstrap .success style, and both buttons - hide.

When clicking the button "Decline" I need to change the corresponding Message status to "Decline" in the database, the corresponding row of table should be bootstrap .danger style, and both buttons - hide.

**message.status** has string type.

I will be grateful for the example of a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your routes, set up a route to accept this request:

Route:

```
get '/setmessagestatus/:status/:id', to: 'messages#set_message_status', as: 'set_message_status'
```

In your controller create the method to set the status:

Messages Controller:

```
def set_message_status
    @message = Message.find(params[:id])
    @message.status = params[:status]
    render :nothing => true
end
```

So now we have the ability in rails to set a request and change the status, now all we need to do is set up the ajax request in your web page.

I have made a simplified html table as example, you will need to edit accordingly, in essence, just ensure in your views you render the info required such as the message id:

HTML:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Message</th>
      <th colspan="2"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <!-- dont display the id on screen if you dont need to, use a data attribute -->
    <tr class="message" data-message_id="1"> 
      <td>This is an example message</td>
      <td>
        <button class="message_status_button" data-status="accept">Accept</button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button class="message_status_button" data-status="decline">Decline</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="message" data-message_id="2">
      <td>This is a second example message</td>
      <td>
        <button class="message_status_button" data-status="accept">Accept</button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button class="message_status_button" data-status="decline">Decline</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.message_status_button').on('click', function() {
    // get whether it was accept or decline
    var status = $(this).data('status');
    // get the message id
    var message_id = $(this).parent().parent().data('message_id');
    // log to console for debugging purposes - feel free to delete:
    console.log("Setting message " + message_id + " status to: " + status);
    // build URL
    var url = "http://yourwebsite/setmessagestatus/" + status + "/" + message_id;
    // send ajax to our rails route //you can expand this to add a callback if need - see jquery .get() docs
    $.get(url);
    // change the class (success/danger bootstrap classes)
    if(status == "accept"){
        //remove danger class if its there
        $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('danger');
        // add success class
        $(this).parent().parent().addClass('success');
    } else {
        //remove success class if its there
        $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('success');
        // add danger class
        $(this).parent().parent().addClass('danger');
    }
});
```

Here's a fiddle of the HTML jQuery bit if it helps: https://jsfiddle.net/ndgz7mut/

I haven't tested any of this but it should do the trick, may need a few tweaks.

Comment: Thanks, Brad! I've adapted the solution to my task and it works almost as required. If you do not mind - please give me a couple of tips.

Comment: How can I change the message status cell at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Further to my last answer, and your comment I had a think and here's the result:

Firstly, When we change the class on the row, we are doing so because the button was clicked, not because the actually row in your database got updated. for example, if for some reason your controller method did not update the status, the row would still turn green (it all happens client side).

A better way around this would be to get your controller to return javascript to the client once it had successfully updated the record in the database. This javascript then adds the success/danger class (or anything else you want to do e.g. update the status)

This will ensure that what the client sees reflects the actual status in the database.

So how do we do that?

Well in your controller, change to the following:

```
def set_message_status
    // set variables so they are available in js view
    @message_id = params[:id]
    @message_status = params[:status]

    # find the message by id
    @message = Message.find(@message_id)

    # if we successfully update the message status:
    if @message.status = @message_status

        # respond with some javascript
        respond_to do |format|
            format.js
        end
     #otherwise, flash message the error   
     else
        respond_to do |format|    
            format.js { flash.now[:notice] = "Update status failed." }
        end
     end
end
```

Now the JavaScript we want to return if the update succeeds is going to live in the relevant views folder

```
-views
|-messages
  |-set_message_status.js.erb
```

In this set_message_status.js.erb we want to have some javascript that will find the correct row in the table, update the status text and add the success/danger class as required.

because its js.erb we can still use ruby inside the javascript and rails will run the ruby first before sending the resulting javascript (same as it does with html.erb)

So our set_message_status.js.erb can look like this:

```
// pass the ruby variables into javascript variables
var messageID = <%= @message_id %>;
var messageStatus = <%= @message_status %>

// find the row of the table based on the data-message_id
var messageRow = $('.message[data-message_id="' + messageID + "'" )

    if(messageStatus == "accept"){
        //remove danger class if its there
        messageRow.removeClass('danger');
        // add success class
        messageRow.addClass('success');

    } else  if(messageStatus == "decline"){
        //remove success class if its there
        messageRow.removeClass('success');
        // add danger class
        messageRow..addClass('danger');
  }

// update the status
    // make sure the td for the status has the class .status
    // look for the td with class status inside the message row.
    // change the html to the message status.
    messageRow.find('.status').html(messageStatus)
```

Lastly, remove the adding/removing of classes from our original js as this will be done by set_message_status.js.erb:

```
$('.message_status_button').on('click', function() {
    // get whether it was accept or decline
    var status = $(this).data('status');
    // get the message id
    var message_id = $(this).parent().parent().data('message_id');
    // log to console for debugging purposes - feel free to delete:
    console.log("Setting message " + message_id + " status to: " + status);
    // build URL
    var url = "http://yourwebsite/setmessagestatus/" + status + "/" + message_id;
    // send ajax to our rails route //you can expand this to add a callback if need - see jquery .get() docs
    $.get(url);
    //
    // <-------------------  **REMOVED THE CLASS ADDING AND REMOVING FROM HERE** 
    //
});
```

Once again, none of this is tested and you may need to tweak to match your specifics but hopefully it gives you there general idea.